# Application logo missing from OneDrive application settings page

Tags: onedrive

I have integrated Microsoft One Drive cloud service to one of my web applications through the REST API.During the time I registered my applications with One Drive through the Application Settings page, I had uploaded application logo's for each of the application which I had registered. But right now when I open it after some days , I find that the logo's which I uploaded for few of the applications are missing while for few, its present as it is. For few applications, it just shows 'Image of a 48 by 48 logo' message in place of the logo. This is kind of weird because I had uploaded the same logo for all the applications initially. Also, when I inspect that image element I find the src attribute for the image has some different location internal to Microsoft and my image is not present there. Even if I try to upload the same image again, it just saves the changes but doesn't show the image there. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Hi Vineetha, can you share the URL of the broken image if you have it? If not, can you share your appid's?

Comment: Hi, Actually the image was uploaded from my desktop..When I view source of the page, this is the url which I see in the src attribute of the <img> tag.                                        https://public.dm2303.livefilestore.com/y2pLDD-461oQopdbImrUDfRjc8H8bEqdIEbFHtdws_jY8yfZwNhYajpezfRbQ5JWoKbZDOzRU5ndg16_r-PZquWBJb-HGzWelJd5opFHHxsm6M?psid=1. In this url the image is not present.But for few other applications, the image is present..I don't know what has happened to it suddenly..Looks weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for this report. We found an issue with some of the icons and it should now be fixed. Your URL works now.